# Creating image size (math.sqrt)

Tags: python

I am running a script that converts a wav file into a png, the problem im having is that I can't load a wav file longer than a 1 second.

I need to change `imageSize = math.sqrt(44100)` to increase the allowed image size, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.  I'd like to load a 60 second wav file instead.

```
#####################
#
# Convert WAV into PNG
# Author: @bobvanluijt
#
#####################

from PIL import Image
import wave, struct, sys, math

##
# Collect input
##
if sys.argv[1][-4:] != '.wav':
    sys.exit("First argument should be a .wav file")

if sys.argv[2][-4:] != '.png':
    sys.exit("Second argument should be a .png file")

##
# Conversion:
##

# Wave file needs to be 16 bit mono
waveFile = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

if waveFile.getnchannels() != 1:
    sys.exit("ERROR: The wave file should be single channel (mono)")

if waveFile.getframerate() != 44100:
    sys.exit("ERROR: The samplerate should be 44,100")

imageRgbArray = list()

waveLength = waveFile.getnframes()

# Create the image size (based on the length)
imageSize = math.sqrt(44100)

# Loop through the wave file
for i in range(0, 44100):

    # Try to read frame, if not possible fill with 0x0
    try:
        waveData = waveFile.readframes(1)
        data = struct.unpack("<h", waveData) # This loads the wave bit
        convertedData = int(data[0]) + 32768 # This adds 16bit/2 (=32768) to the data
    except:
        convertedData = 0
        pass

    # This converts the number into a hex value.
    convertedDataHex = hex(convertedData)

    # convert the value to a string and strips first two characters 
    hexString = str(convertedDataHex)[2:]

    # Check how much the string should be prefixed to get the color hex length (= 6 char)
    count = 6 - len(hexString)

    # Prefix with a zero
    while (count > 0):
        hexString = "0" + hexString 
        count -= 1

    # Convert into RGB value
    rgbData = tuple(int(hexString[i:i + 6 // 3], 16) for i in range(0, 6, 6 // 3)) # Convert to RGB data

    # Add the RGB value to the image array
    imageRgbArray.append(rgbData)

# Create new image
im = Image.new('RGB', (int(imageSize), int(imageSize)))

# Add image data
im.putdata(imageRgbArray)

# Save image
im.save(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Please show your attempts to solve the problem and come up with a specific question.

Comment: How is the code in your question not working (assuming it's making an attempt to do what you want)? If it's producing errors or exceptions are being raised, please [edit] your question and describe it or them (and copy and paste them into it as well).

Comment: There are no errors, I just dont know how to change the file size to accomodate longer audio files. Im assuming math.sqrt(44100) means "square root of", which is 210...pixels?

Answer (score 0):

If the sample rate is 44100, then the image size should be the square root 44100 times the audio length.

try replacing

```
imageSize = math.sqrt(44100)
```

with

```
imageSize = math.sqrt(44100*60)
```

assuming that your wav file is exactly 60 seconds.

Comment: Hmm...nope, this still doesnt work...I am loading a 5MB 60 second audio clip, and it returns a 55KB PNG. Somethings not right

Comment: wav files are uncompressed.  pngs ars compressed.

Comment: 5MB to 55KB? Are you positive about that? Wouldnt the image get bigger the longer the audio?